# Отправка всех отмеченных checkbox одной переменной

Tags: php

У меня есть список из большого количества checkbox, отмечаем их галочками и отправляем на PHP. В PHP получаем каждую строчку (checkbox) отдельной переменной (POST).

Как можно отправить все отмеченные checkbox одной переменной (например, через запятую все value), что бы легко было обрабатывать?

Answer (score 4):

Дайте имя чекбоксу `name="check[0]"`, другому `name="check[1]"` и т.д. на стороне `PHP` вы получите массив `$_POST['check']`, и соответственно `$_POST['check']` будет иметь следующую стркутуру `array(0 => value0, 1 => value1, ... );` где `value0` - значение атрибута `value` чекбокса с именем `name="check[0]"`, `value1` - значение атрибута `value` чекбокса с именем `name="check[1]"` и т.д.

В $_POST['check'] попадут значения только тех чекбоксов, которые были отмечены галочкой.

Comment: Попробуйте **`name="check[]"`**, если не в курсе)

Comment: @Sh4dow, эм, не самая лучшая идея, учитывая то что на странице много чекбоксов и некторые из них могут иметь одинаковые значения, как тогда прикажете узнавать был ли отмечен конретный чекбокс?

Comment: Паралельно с массивом check[] сформируйте массив check_name[] в виде hidden input и в нем передайте информацию которая будет необходима для сверки. Значению check[0] будет соответствовать check_name[0]. Не самая лучшая реализация, но вполне приемлема :-)

Comment: @Зоркий, зачем еще один массив? когда задав `name="check[1]"` я буду точно уверен, что если `isset($_POST['check'][1]) == TRUE` то этот чекбокс нажат.

Comment: ну обычно множественные селекты - это что-то типа линковки товар-категори**и**, и чекбоксы выглядят как **`<input type="checkbox" name="productLink[<?=$item->?>][]" value="<?=$cat->id?>" />`**. Не всегда применимо, ага.

Comment: Записи

name="check[]" name="check[]" name="check[]"
и
name="check[0]" name="check[1]" name="check[2]"
идентичны.
Я подумал что вы хотите не просто получить значение от чекбокса в массиве, но и ассоциировать его с тем что это за чекбокс был. Поэтому посоветовал то что посоветовал. Если такой задачи не стоит то ответ выше написан :)

Comment: @Sh4dow, разумеется, все зависит от задачи, но основная фишка вставлять номера - быстрая проверка выделен ли конкретный чекбокс или нет, весьма утомительно использовать `array_search`. Конечно можно сделать [`array_flip`][1], но по мне так это извращение, зачем отказываться от стандартного механизма.

@Зоркий, `name="check[]"` не применим например тогда когда требуется перенести какой-то чекбокс выше его текущей позиции, в результате чего его id в массиве check сместится, собственно о таких случаях я и говорю.

[1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-flip.php

Comment: Ну запоминать чекбоксы по номерам - id тоже не очень :)

Answer (score 1):

Резюмирую вышесказанное: задайте чекбоксам имена вида `name="myName[]"`, тогда при отправке формы данные придут в виде массива $_POST['myName'] - его и надо разбирать.
Если вам важно знать, какой чекбокс соответствует какой записи (например, у вас список товаров), используйте именование вида `name="myName[itemId]"`, где itemId - id записи. Тогда данные также придут в виде массива, но ключами будут служить те самые itemId. А разбирать массив придется через foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Я имел подобную задачу и просто делал имена цифровые для чекбоксов(можно с префиксами), в пхп же перебирал весь массив POST.

Следующий скрипт выведет весь массив POST в виде таблицы

```
<?php
echo "<table>";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){

echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>$value</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

А что мешает "почистить" массив и обрабатывать. В $_POST, стандартно, 8 мегабайт влазает. Вам будет, где развернуться.

```
array_diff($array,array(''));
```